# Saving webshop product id with jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

If i click the button, how can i save the product ID into jquery cookie?

I have the code below, but i think its not the best, or a great solution. There is another problem too, i always get the message, that id saved to the favorites.

It doesnt check, that if the actual id is in the favorites.

```
$('#favorite_button').click(function()
{
     var cookie_message, item_id, most_van;

     item_id = <?php echo (int)$id; ?>;
     var cookie_val = $.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie");
     if (cookie_val)
     {
         most_van = cookie_val.split(";");
     }
     else
     {
         most_van = [];
     }

     if ($.inArray(item_id, most_van) === -1)
     {
         most_van.push(item_id);
         $.removeCookie('kedvenc_termek_cookie');
         $.cookie('kedvenc_termek_cookie', most_van.join(";"), { expires: 7, path: "/" });
         cookie_message = "Added to favorites";
     }
     else
     {
         cookie_message = "This ID is alredy saved in the favorites";
     }
 });
```

Can someone give me a good, and simple code, instead of this?

**Updated:**

I only get the ID 70 product listed.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if ($.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie"))
    {
        var favorite_items_id = $.cookie("kedvenc_termek_cookie");
        console.log(favorite_items_id);
        $( "#favorite_items" ).load( "files/kedvencek.php?id="+favorite_items_id, function() {
            var items_loaded = 1;
            $("#favorite_items").append('<div class="clear"></div>');
        });
    }
});


<div class="items_container" id="favorite_items"></div>

<?php
session_start();
if (file_exists("connect.php")) {include_once("connect.php");}
if (file_exists("functions.php")) {include_once("functions.php");}
$id = explode('|' , $_GET["id"]);
foreach( $id AS $i)
{
    $lista[] = intval($i);
}
$list = implode(',' , $lista );
$sql = "SELECT termek_id, termek_nev FROM termek WHERE termek_status = 1 AND termek_id in ($list) ORDER BY termek_nev ASC";
$get_main_items = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
if(mysqli_num_rows($get_main_items) > 0 )
{
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_main_items))
    {
        echo '<h2>'.$i['termek_nev'].'</h2>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo ' Még nincs kedvenc termék!';
}
die();
?>
```

And the console:
[image]
[image]

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: There arent any errors. In the console, i only display the id-s, wich are in the cookie. (this isnt in this code)

I searched for codes, for this target, but nothing good.

Comment: fix all your console errors first then run this code

Comment: But i dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, this was it:  $id = explode('|' , $_GET["id"]);

I needed a ; in the explode.